# Reading integers in a .txt file (Java)

Tags: java, input, syntax, output, file-handling

So basically I'm trying to write a program where someone can enter 10 integers, that would then be saved in a .txt file, then opened and averaged together.

I'm doing pretty good so far, I got all the exception handling and saving a file with my inputted integers down, but I'm unsure how to read the file. I'm assuming calculating the average wouldn't be difficult once I have that all done anyways. Here's part of my code with the rest linked below (I really think you'd need to see the full code to better recognize the issue):

```
public static void closeFile()
{
    if (output != null)
        output.close();
}
public static void readRecords()
{
    try
    {
        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.printf("%s%n", String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/yW6G8N8C

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the file properly, you need to use a reader for that:

```
public static void readRecords(){
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("numbers.txt"))) {
        String line;
        int[] number = new int[10];
        i=-1;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            number[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
            System.out.println("number "+i+" = "+number[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        // Handle the trouble
    }
}
```

I am not entirely sure what you want to do with your numbers you get or the exact format of the `numbers.txt` file but I am assuming you are doing something sensible, like writing one integer per line to your file. Otherwise, adjust the code accordingly to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as mentioned by chalarangelo you are not opening the file correctly. You can use `Formatter` class to write to file but you can't read from file using that. So you need to use a proper reader like `BufferedReader` and use its `readLine()` method.

That aside is it necessary that you store integers together with the string 
"Inputted integer: "... If so then its going to be a bit difficult to just get the numbers. I'd advise printing just numbers into the file i.e just do

`output.format("%s%n", String.valueOf(numbers[i]));`

instead of

`output.format("Inputted integer: %s%n", String.valueOf(numbers[i]));`

After that use a reader and read the line and convert it into integer and store it in the array as mentioned in chalarengo's answer.